# Can't find control(checkbox) in GridView EditTemplate via RowEditing

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a GridView

```
<EditItemTemplate>
 <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" 
  oncheckedchanged="CheckBox_CheckedChanged" />
   </EditItemTemplate>
```

The result is always the same, a NULL is returned. my problem is can't find control end  Insert Visible colum true/false.

Comment: please update the question with the code you already tried

Comment: when you want to get value?

Comment: Where and How did you find your checkbox ?

Answer (score 3):

```
protected void grdPractices_OnRowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
{
  this.grdPractices.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
  var vCheckBox = this.grdPractices.Rows[e.NewEditIndex].Controls[0].FindControl("chkSites") as CheckBox;
  if (vCheckBox == null)
  {
     return;
  }
}
```

**UPDATE**

In OnRowEditing event you can get the index of the gridview which row you want to edit.Then using the index,you can findcontrol the checkbox.Verify checkbox varible is null or do whatever.

Comment: please give some description about your answer,that how it will solve the problem of user and what this code functionality is.

Comment: In OnRowEditing event you can get the index of the gridview which row you want to edit.Then using the index,you can findcontrol the checkbox.Verify checkbox varible is null and do whatever ..:)

Answer (score 1):

```
var chk = (CheckBox)(e.item.FindControl("CheckBox"))
```

This code will return your checkbox control.

Comment: question is tagged as C#

Answer (score 0):

On PostBack You can get it like this:

```
  protected void CheckBox_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            CheckBox chkbox = (CheckBox)sender;

            //now its available for you
        }
```

On RowCommand get it like this (assuming your command button is LinkButon):

```
protected void grd_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
 GridViewRow grd = (GridViewRow)(((LinkButton)e.CommandSource).NamingContainer);
 int rowindex = grd.RowIndex;
 CheckBox chkbox = (CheckBox)grd.Rows[rowindex].FindControl("checkboxId"); 
// do whatever
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 protected void GridView1_OnRowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
       {
        GridViewRow row = GridView1.Rows[e.NewEditIndex];
        bool IsChecked = ((CheckBox)(row.Cells[0].FindControl("chkbox"))).Checked;
       }
```